# MySQL Equivalent Query or JOIN query

Tags: mysql

The query below works pefectly in SQL Server

```
update userrole 
set userid = 6 where userid = 5
and id not in 
(
  select b.id from userrole a inner join userrole b
  on a.roleid = b.roleid and a.region = b.region
  where a.userid = 6 and b.userid = 5
)
```

When I use the same query in MYSQL, I get the exception 1093 which says Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'userrole' for update in FROM clause.

1. How to change the query to MySQL equivalent?
2. How to use JOIN query instead of sub-query in the above query

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better to post the task, not the possible solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don 't try to understand the meaning of the request and simply adapt it to MySQL then:

```sql
UPDATE userrole ur
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT b.id 
            FROM userrole a 
            INNER JOIN userrole b ON a.roleid = b.roleid 
                                 AND a.region = b.region
            WHERE a.userid = 6 
              AND b.userid = 5 ) sq ON ur.id = sq.id
SET ur.userid = 6 
WHERE ur.userid = 5
WHERE sq.id IS NULL
```

If you try to understand the task then it looks like (it seems) "alter `userid` from 5 to 6 if the record with the same `(roleid,region)` and `userid=6` not exists yet". If so the task may be solved by:

```sql
UPDATE userrole t1
LEFT JOIN userrole t2 ON (t1.roleid, t1.region) = (t2.roleid, t2.region)
                     AND t2.userid = 6
SET t1.userid = 6
WHERE t1.useris = 5
  AND t2.userid IS NULL
```